# Issue in Material Design Components for ios

Tags: ios, material-design

I am trying to use Material Design SnackBar in iOS.
I was able to add the Material Design Library, but while running I am getting the below error.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MDCSnackbarManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DetailScreenViewController.o

Comment: Can you show the cod for `DetailScreenViewController`? Did you import the library/header? How did you jntegrate it - manually or via Cocoapods/Carthage?

Comment: I used Cocoapods. I followed this link.
https://material.io/develop/ios/components/snackbars/
It compiles perfectly, but shows error when I am trying to run.

Comment: Just to be sure - you are using the `xcworkspace` generated by Cocoapods?

Comment: yes. I am using xcworkspace.